# Organization of correlated columns in Netezza

Tags: netezza

Say there is a large table in Netezza with columns COUNTRY and REGION where each country rolls up to a region. If the table is organized explicitly only on COUNTRY, it is implicitly organized also on REGION because the data are correlated.

Does Netezza know this for queries that use REGION in the WHERE clause, or does Netezza still scan the whole table regardless of the zone maps?

Put another way: to get the performance benefit for REGION, must REGION be explicitly organized in the zone map?

Answer (score 1):

The sport answer is ‘yes’ the slightly longer answer is ‘it depends’

Generally speaking netezza zonemaps works for all columns except string columns which only has a zonemaps on them if they are included in the ‘organize on’, so let’s assume that both columns are integer ‘codes’ and you have a small table (dimension tables) that translates each of the two codes to a string through a join, then it will work nicely.

Of course this optimization works best if the number of distinct values are small compared to the entire table and/or the region codes are for the most part ascending when the corresponding country codes are ascending.

Comment: Our tables uses strings, not integers. In one of my real examples, there are 3 region codes and 25 countries.

Comment: In that case you might need to include both in the ‘organize’  (remember to groom, records all). The real question is if is a significant benefit with your particular workload. Generally the value of each added column to ‘organize on’ decreases rapidly. I would urge you to change your data model though, especially if the strings are more than a few bytes